# Node.js - connecting to IBM Watson Assistant fails

Tags: node.js, watson-assistant

I am using example from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm-watson#assistant-v1  to connect to my Watson Assistant workspace however I get the following error:

```
{ Not Found: Resource not found
    at RequestWrapper.formatError (/Users/honza/Desktop/node_modules/ibm-cloud-sdk-core/lib/request-wrapper.js:208:21)
    at /Users/honza/Desktop/node_modules/ibm-cloud-sdk-core/lib/request-wrapper.js:196:25
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
name: 'Not Found',
  code: 404,
  message: 'Resource not found',
  body: '{"error":"Resource not found","code":404}',
```

I have done 'npm install ibm-watson' in the folder with  the example app, supplied the api_key, url and workspace id.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any guidance.

Jan.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Seems the problem is with one of the Watson Assistant instances, where the url was not correct. I created new service and now it works.

Comment: You should write a detailed answer and mark your question answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a "Resource not found" 404, try changing:

```
import DiscoveryV1 from 'ibm-watson/discovery/v1';
```

to

```
import DiscoveryV1 from 'ibm-watson/assistant/v1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Skill ID being passed as an input is incorrect.